# Make a read only "view" of a network folder

Tags: windows-7

I feel like this should be easy and I'm missing something simple.

We have a network folder A that must be full access to a user to support a legacy application. However, we also need the user to be able to read and copy files from that folder. Any changes the user makes manually in/to that folder will be problematic.

So far, I've considered two options:

1. Create a folder B which functions as a mirror or read-only view of folder A.
2. Map a drive to A and somehow set the mapping to read only.

I realise the second option is conceptually flawed.

This would be trivially easy if we could create a user with only read permissions and then map a drive to A with that user. Assume this is impossible.

Assume also that I can't change the requirements, download any non-native applications, or even really enter into a meaningful discussion with my manager. The folder is also going to be stupidly large, so a full copy is not really an option.

Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Create a second share for the same folder, and configure the share permissions to read-only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The user must have full access to the folder and also must have read access (which is already covered by full access permissions)? Were you talking about different users?

Comment: I think you're (@Jason) missing something simple.  You say "Map a drive to A and somehow set the mapping to read only." is conceptually flawed, but the concept is sound, the implementation is flawed. You suggest setting the perm's on the client side mapping; but rather (as @Harry is saying) you need to set the permissions on a second access point on the server side. So, you have //server/data and //server/data-ro; both resolve to the same physical storage. Users (who are allowed) can map the first share for full access, and other users map the second drive for read-only access.